# Upper measure of a single element set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know that the upper measure of a finite set is 0, but I was wondering how would I prove that the upper measure of a single element, $a$, is 0. I was thinking of taking $(a-\epsilon, a+ \epsilon)$ and taking the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Would that work? (if I disregard endpoints)

Comment: instead of bracket you mean (), right?

Comment: yea, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is the right one.  You can just notice that the single point set $\{a\}$ is contained in the interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ and so has measure less than $2\epsilon$.  This holds for every positive $\epsilon$ so your set has measure zero.